# CUPS - HP Photosmart C4280

Tags: cups

First crack at using CUPS to setup a print server, I have a HP Photosmart C4280 but it's not listed as a printer in my CUPS install (and looking at the listed Photosmart prints none are even similar to mine).

Any ideas which printer I could choose instead, or where I can find a PPD file for this printer?

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at [OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/drivers) if your printer is not supported right now... you seem to have only two options... try any driver till you get any of them to work, or just see if there is an older driver for your printer that may do the work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this printer is supported by the [HPLIP drivers](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/photosmart/photosmart_c4200_series.html). I don't have one of these printers, so cannot test it. See the C4280 listing on that page. In general HP printers have good Linux support, and its printer drivers are usually free software as well.

You don't state your distribution, but these drivers are packaged for Debian and therefore Ubuntu, and presumably other major Linux distributions as well. If a sufficiently recent version of the driver is not available for your distribution, it should be trivial to backport it.